# sql works only in mysql but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, centos

im running into a rather strange error.

i write my sql queries in mysql to ensure they are working, before i implement them.

This Query works fine:

```
SELECT articles.article_id,
       articles.previewtext,
       articles.date,
       articles.title,
       articles.previewtext,
       image.thumbnail,
       articleAuthTable.nickname AS authorNickname,
       imageAuthTable.nickname   AS imageNickname
FROM   articles
       LEFT JOIN image
              ON articles.previewimage = image.image_id
       LEFT JOIN authors AS articleAuthTable
              ON articles.author = articleAuthTable.author_id
       LEFT JOIN authors AS imageAuthTable
              ON image.author = imageAuthTable.author_id
WHERE  articles.categories = 'gamedev'
       AND articles.article_id > 0
ORDER  BY date DESC;
```

so i implemented it in my php class (as always) and tried to obtain the results. They are empty and result in an "you have an error in you mysql".
As always i tried to echo the query as a string and rerun it in mysql. Works like a charm. In php it doesnt. Same error.

i tried to cut the sql query in pieces, to find the error, which seems to be only present in the statement:

```
[...] articles.article_id > 0
```

this triggers my php sql query to crash. It wont work in any way in php. But in mysql it works flawlessly and i get the correct data. Any other SQL Query in php works flawlessly.

The part that doesnt work should limit the results.

EDIT:
PHP Code

```
public function queryWhile($query){
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
        if(!$this->result){
            echo "No response";
            $this->closeDB();

        }else{
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result)){
                $this->resultArray[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }

        return $this->queryWhile("SELECT articles.article_id, articles.PreviewText, articles.date,articles.Title, articles.previewText, image.thumbnail, articleAuthTable.nickname AS authorNickname, imageAuthTable.nickname AS imageNickname FROM articles LEFT JOIN image ON articles.previewImage = image.image_id LEFT JOIN authors AS articleAuthTable ON articles.author = articleAuthTable.author_id LEFT JOIN authors AS imageAuthTable ON image.author = imageAuthTable.author_id WHERE articles.categories = '".$this->category."' ORDER BY date DESC;");
```

Comment: so, show us the PHP/MySQL connection etc.

Comment: And the PHP code you're making the call with?

Comment: date is a reserved word. you shouldn't use that for your column name, but since you already did, you should enclose that field in backticks.

Comment: @Pamblam `date` is a keyword, not a reserved word. Do you see an `(R)` in the docs next to it? no ;-) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: well.. it's some kinda word

Comment: whoever upvote the comment about `date` is wrong and blew a vote for nothing. RT*M https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: edit: your post is in another answer

Comment: That is not how it works ^

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: @Fred -ii using ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); im not getting any error or warnings.

Comment: That ^ will not "display" but only log if logs are enabled on your system. You need to display them also `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: thanks, still no warnings nor errors.

Comment: the use of `$this` implies the use of a class that you're not showing us. As per an error I see below, either your category is empty/not set, or you're using the wrong type for the column, or something else is breaking your query somewhere. `WHERE articles.categories = '".$this->category."' ORDER BY date DESC;");` is most likely failing here as per `the right syntax to use near '0 ORDER BY date DESC' at line 1` - notice the `near '0` ? That's where the error starts.

Comment: and we have no idea what `queryWhile()` that function works like. Plus, make sure you're using the same MySQL API to connect with as your query, which is `mysqli_`. If you're using `mysql_` or PDO to connect with, then that's a problem. I believe you have enough to go on now to further debug your code and you may want to include your class/functions in your question, because as it stands, this is more guesswork for everyone. Good luck.

Comment: My recommendation: escape `$this->category` and try again.

Comment: The queryWhile function only escapes the query and calls mysqli_query. its edited and added to the original post. The Class only holds connection and and variables for queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);
```

is converting

```
articles.article_id > 0
```

to

```
articles.article_id &gt; 0
```

Which MySQL obviously has no idea what to do with. There is really no good reason I can think of to use `htmlspecialchars` on an SQL statement, unless you are intending to print it out on a web page.

Comment: thank you, your answer is right. I had a misconception about htmlspecialchars.